# Amazon instance automatically creating and resizing partitions after VM Import

Tags: centos, filesystems, partition, virtual-machine, amazon

I'm using Packer to create a VM with CentOS 7, and exporting it as a `.ova` file at the final of installation.
By default, Packer creates a 40GB Virtual Disk (`.vmdk`). After the installation, if I import the .`ova` file in VirtualBox (just for tests) and list the file system of the created VM, I got this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   37G  1.6G   35G   5% /
devtmpfs             1.3G     0  1.3G   0% /dev
tmpfs                1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                1.4G  8.4M  1.3G   1% /run
tmpfs                1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1014M  166M  849M  17% /boot
tmpfs                268M     0  268M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                268M     0  268M   0% /run/user/0
```

If I import the same `.ova` file in a Amazon Instance, this time increasing the size of my root storage volume to 100GB, I got this file system:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   50G  4,0G   46G   9% /
devtmpfs              15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 15G   18M   15G   1% /run
tmpfs                 15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1          1014M  185M  830M  19% /boot
/dev/mapper/cl-home   45G   89M   45G   1% /home
tmpfs                3,0G     0  3,0G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                3,0G     0  3,0G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Note that the `/` was increased to 50GB, and now a new `/home` was automatically created.
This was driving me crazy, until I find the cause:
All the instalallation was made automatically by Packer, using a kickstart config file wich uses `autopart` for partitioning.
In RedHat docs, I found this:

```
autopart (optional)
Automatically creates partitions: a root (/) partition (1 GB or larger), a swap partition, and an appropriate /boot partition for the architecture. On large enough drives (50 GB and larger), this also creates a /home partition.
```

So, I decided to manually create the partitions, using this lines in the kickstart file instead of `autopart`:

```
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size=1014
part pv.01 --size=1000 --grow
volgroup cl pv.01
logvol swap --fstype swap --name=swap --vgname=cl --size=2048
logvol / --fstype ext4 --name=root --vgname=cl --size=1 --grow
```

Importing the `.ova` again to Amazon, selecting the same storage size of 100GB for the root volume, I finally got what I wanted:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   94G  2,3G   87G   3% /
devtmpfs              15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 15G     0   15G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 15G  8,3M   15G   1% /run
tmpfs                 15G     0   15G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1           983M  154M  762M  17% /boot
tmpfs                3,0G     0  3,0G   0% /run/user/1000
```

So I found **WHAT** is going on, but not **HOW** it happens. The questions are:

- The kickstart file is supposed to be used only in installation time.
  How after Amazon VM import the file system get changed using the same
  conventions of the kickstart installation?
- Where this info is stored, and how the resizing is being done
  automatically in CentOS 7?

Comment: check `cloud-init` config in the image. possibly packer is using autopart from kickstart config for `cloud-init` ?

Comment: ignore above, it can't be cloud-init

Comment: @VenkatC, I also thought that it could be cloud init, but it not works with LVM, which is my case...Thanks!